# why widget not refreshing even after wrapped with obx in getx flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am learning getx and here i am facing a problem

I hve created a userModel with name and age field and showing on screen

when i tap on elevated button i am changing any name and it should be refresh as i have wrapped text widget into Obx but still not working...Whats the reason?

```
class UserModel
{
  String name;
  String age;
  UserModel({required this.name,required this.age});

  static UserModel empty()=>UserModel(name: '', age: '');
}

class UserController extends GetxController
{
  Rx<UserModel> loggedUser=UserModel.empty().obs;


  void changeName(String name)
  {
    loggedUser.value.name=name;
   
  }

}
```

this is screen code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller=Get.put(UserController());
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Obx(() {
          return Column(

          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [

             Text('Name :'+controller.loggedUser.value.name),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
             Text('Age: '+controller.loggedUser.value.age),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
            controller.changeName('xyz');
            }, child: const Text('Change')),

            Spacer(),
          ],);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have notice that you are forwarding this  link of 'why not getx' whenever a question arise in getx.. is that really not good to user GETx?

Comment: The video often raises issues that people haven't considered, many of whom have thanked me for pointing this out.  So yes, I share the video ANY time I see GetX mentioned, while I'm not ultimately mandating that everyone stop using it.  Just be informed what you're giving up.

Comment: use Obx only for Text widgets separately not in column. let me know if it fixes your bug or not

Comment: not issue with wrapping by column or text...i missed to refresh object..and found answer but looking for better solution if it has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have set loggedUser as obs and its targetting entire object to be obs

so you need to update entire object

and if you are updating only one or few properties of object you need to call refresh method after updating properties..

so implement your coding as below in your changeName method

```
void changeName(String name)
  {
    loggedUser.value.name=name;
//above code...you are updating a property not entire object


    loggedUser.refresh();// add this line to your code to refresh entire object

   
  }
```

Comment: instead of setting all object property to obs , use refresh method..i think this is better

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I last used GetX, but if I recall correctly when declaring the `UserModel` instance as `Rx<UserModel> loggedUser = UserModel.empty().obs`, you will need to update the entire `UserModel` instance, not just its properties.

Use `loggedUser.value = newUser` instead of `loggedUser.value.name = name`.

If you still want to use `loggedUser.value.name=name`, consider modifying the `UserModel` as shown below:

```
class UserModel
{
  final RxString name;
  final RxString age;
  UserModel({required this.name,required this.age});

  factory UserModel.empty() => UserModel(name: ''.obs, age: ''.obs);
}
```

Good luck and happy coding!